# Calling C++ DLL from C# within VS fails. Run exe outside VS and it works

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, calling-convention

I have a C++ DLL that is being called like below from a C# console app.

When run in Visual Studio to debug it, it throws an exception saying the stack is unstable and to check that the method arguments are correct.  However, if I run the *.exe outside of VS from Windows Explorer it retuns data to the screen as expected.

How can I get this to run within Visual Studio?

Thanks

```
**From the C++ header file:**
#ifdef RFIDSVRCONNECT_EXPORTS
#define RFID_CONN_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define RFID_CONN_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

RFID_CONN_API BSTR rscListDevices( long showall ) ;


[DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string rscListDevices(int showall);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string data= rscListDevices(0);
  Console.WriteLine(data);
  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What is the correct method signature from the C/C++ header file? Probably the problem is your P/Invoke signature is incorrect.

Comment: RFID_CONN_API BSTR rscListDevices( long showall ) ;

Comment: How is RFID_CONN_API defined?

Comment: @NikolayKhil updated question with RFID_CONN_API defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you're using the same calling convention in both [C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx).

I suspect that the [`/Gd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46t77ak2.aspx) compiler option is set (since it is set by default), so [`__cdecl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) is used as default calling convention for unmarked functions.

You can fix crashes by either specifing the same calling convention in your C# code:

```
[DllImport("MyDLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl))]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
public static extern string rscListDevices(int showall);
```

Or changing `rscListDevices`'s calling convention to [`__stdcall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (which is the default in C#):

```
RFID_CONN_API BSTR __stdcall rscListDevices( long showall ) ;
```

You can also set `__stdcall` as the default calling convention for the unmarked functions in your C++ DLL by changing compiler option from /Gd to /Gz in manually or using the Project Properties dialog:
[image: changing the default calling convention in Visual Studio]

But if you **really** want to disable MDA, you can go Debug->Exceptions and uncheck Managed Debugging Assistance.

You can read more about pInvokeStackImbalance and MDA [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0htdy0k3.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather get the C++ referencing and if needs be change the C++ code to get this working. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jon, there is no right or wrong C++ calling convention, all that matters is that the C++ and C# conventions match.

Comment: That works with the CallingConvention in VS2012 but not in VS2010. VS2010 returns a blank string

Comment: @Jon please update your question with function body. I suspect something wrong there.